# How do I get to the STOMP plugin for RabbitMQ on Heroku

Tags: heroku, browser, rabbitmq, stomp

I'm trying to build a demo of subscribing to AMQP messages from a browser. I've built examples that work using Websockets + the RabbitMQ STOMP plugin on an Heroku app. However, I cannot work out how to get to STOMP in Heroku from a browser on my PC. Currently I'm publishing from RabbitMQ in Heroku to another broker on my PC and accessing the STOMP data from there.

How do I find (can I find?) the STOMP endpoint for my app in Heroku?

heroku config gives me the CLOUDAMQP_URL, which I'm using to get to RabbitMQ.

Comment: Did you try the default port? ws://{CLOUDAMQP_URL}:61614/stomp?

Comment: not yet. presumably I'm going to need to doctor CLOUDAMQP_URL somewhat as it looks like this: CLOUDAMQP_URL: amqp://<8 letter code>:<32 character code>@lemur.cloudamqp.com/<8 letter code>. I'll try with and with substituting the amqp: with ws:.  I didn't spot that default value. Where should I have looked?

Comment: Playing with this, I think that I need to use http://, or the browser barfs with a Cross Origin Request error. So either I'm going to need a port exposed for the stomp protocol, or an endpoint on port 80. (I think).  http://app-base-url:61614/stomp gives a 404.

Comment: This is what I had found: http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/ What library are you using on the client?